# How can I verify what dynamic linker is used when a program is run?

Tags: c, linux, dynamic-linking

I would like to verify that the dynamic linker used when a program is run is the one mentioned via `file`, `readelf -l`, or `ldd`. My motivation stems from having multiple dynamic linkers that exist in separate spaces on the machine and they should never mix-and-match.

Thus far, the best way I have found to verify the dynamic linker is via `gdb`. By looking at output of `info proc mappings`, I can determine which dynamic linker was mapped into the address space and is in use. I am trying to avoid using `gdb` as it would require me to run test suites and other things through it.

Using the `LD_DEBUG` environment variable seems like it could be an alternate solution which would allow me to easily save logs for verification after (or during) program execution. However, I am unsure which option would give me the best information. I thought `scopes` or `libs` could be good options but `libs` doesn't always mention the dynamic linker. For example, this is the output of a simple hello world program:

```
$ LD_DEBUG=libs ./test0
     24579: find library=libc.so.6 [0]; searching
     24579:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
     24579:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
     24579:
     24579:
     24579: calling init: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
     24579:
     24579:
     24579: initialize program: ./test0
     24579:
     24579:
     24579: transferring control: ./test0
     24579:
hello world
     24579:
     24579: calling fini: ./test0 [0]
     24579:
$ LD_DEBUG=libs ./test0-gnu-cross
     24581: find library=libc.so.6 [0]; searching
     24581:  search path=/usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v4:/usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v3:/usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v2:/usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/tls/haswell/avx512_1/x86_64:/usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/tls/haswell/avx512_1:/usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/tls/haswell/x86_64:/usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/tls/haswell:/usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/tls/avx512_1/x86_64:/usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/tls/avx512_1:/usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/tls/x86_64:/usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/tls:/usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/haswell/avx512_1/x86_64:/usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/haswell/avx512_1:/usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/haswell/x86_64:/usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/haswell:/usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/avx512_1/x86_64:/usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/avx512_1:/usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/x86_64:/usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib     (RPATH from file ./test0-gnu-cross)
     24581:   trying file=/usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v4/libc.so.6
     24581:   trying file=/usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v3/libc.so.6
     24581:   trying file=/usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v2/libc.so.6
     24581:   trying file=/usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/tls/haswell/avx512_1/x86_64/libc.so.6
     24581:   trying file=/usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/tls/haswell/avx512_1/libc.so.6
     24581:   trying file=/usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/tls/haswell/x86_64/libc.so.6
     24581:   trying file=/usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/tls/haswell/libc.so.6
     24581:   trying file=/usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/tls/avx512_1/x86_64/libc.so.6
     24581:   trying file=/usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/tls/avx512_1/libc.so.6
     24581:   trying file=/usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/tls/x86_64/libc.so.6
     24581:   trying file=/usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/tls/libc.so.6
     24581:   trying file=/usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/haswell/avx512_1/x86_64/libc.so.6
     24581:   trying file=/usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/haswell/avx512_1/libc.so.6
     24581:   trying file=/usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/haswell/x86_64/libc.so.6
     24581:   trying file=/usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/haswell/libc.so.6
     24581:   trying file=/usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/avx512_1/x86_64/libc.so.6
     24581:   trying file=/usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/avx512_1/libc.so.6
     24581:   trying file=/usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/x86_64/libc.so.6
     24581:   trying file=/usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/libc.so.6
     24581:
     24581:
     24581: calling init: /usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
     24581:
     24581:
     24581: calling init: /usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/libc.so.6
     24581:
     24581:
     24581: initialize program: ./test0-gnu-cross
     24581:
     24581:
     24581: transferring control: ./test0-gnu-cross
     24581:
hello world
     24581:
     24581: calling fini: ./test0-gnu-cross [0]
     24581:
```

As you can see, the program `test0` which is built with a standard Debian/GNU toolchain and uses the system's dynamic linker doesn't state that.

The `scopes` option looks more helpful but I don't understand what the output is saying:

```
$ LD_DEBUG=scopes ./test0
     24577:
     24577: Initial object scopes
     24577: object=./test0 [0]
     24577:  scope 0: ./test0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
     24577:
     24577: object=linux-vdso.so.1 [0]
     24577:  scope 0: ./test0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
     24577:  scope 1: linux-vdso.so.1
     24577:
     24577: object=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0]
     24577:  scope 0: ./test0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
     24577:
     24577: object=/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 [0]
     24577:  no scope
     24577:
hello world
$ LD_DEBUG=scopes ./test0-gnu-cross
     24576:
     24576: Initial object scopes
     24576: object=./test0-gnu-cross [0]
     24576:  scope 0: ./test0-gnu-cross /usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/libc.so.6 /usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
     24576:
     24576: object=linux-vdso.so.1 [0]
     24576:  scope 0: ./test0-gnu-cross /usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/libc.so.6 /usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
     24576:  scope 1: linux-vdso.so.1
     24576:
     24576: object=/usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/libc.so.6 [0]
     24576:  scope 0: ./test0-gnu-cross /usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/libc.so.6 /usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
     24576:
     24576: object=/usr/local/gnu-cross/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 [0]
     24576:  no scope
     24576:
hello world
```

In summary, I would like to find a good way to verify the dynamic linker that is being used. Unless you can think of a better option, `LD_DEBUG` seems like a good bet, but I struggle to understand how to use it effectively in this case.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: `info proc mappings` appears to provide the information contained in `/proc/self/maps`, so just reading the latter may be sufficient

Comment: @CraigEstey with that solution would I not have to race to read `/proc/<pid>/maps` before the program terminates? Is there a way to predict what PID will be generated next and then wait on its creation in `/proc`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is *no* need to actually *run* the executable to determine the ELF interpreter that it *will* use.

We can use static tools and be guaranteed that we can get the full path.

We can use a combination of `readelf` and `ldd`.

If we use `readelf -a`, we can parse the output.

---

One part of the `readelf` output:

```
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
  [ 0]                   NULL             0000000000000000  00000000
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     0
  [ 1] .interp           PROGBITS         00000000000002e0  000002e0
       000000000000001c  0000000000000000   A       0     0     1
```

Note the *address* of the `.interp` section. It is `0x2e0`.

---

If we open the executable and do a seek to that offset, we can read the ELF interpreter string. For example, here is [what I'll call] `fileBad`:

```
000002e0: 2F6C6962 36342F7A 642D6C69 6E75782D  /lib64/zd-linux-
000002f0: 7838362D 36342E73 6F2E3200 00000000  x86-64.so.2.....
```

Note that the string seems a little odd ... More on that later ...

---

Under the "Program Headers:" section, we have:

```
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  PHDR           0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000000040
                 0x00000000000002a0 0x00000000000002a0  R      0x8
  INTERP         0x00000000000002e0 0x00000000000002e0 0x00000000000002e0
                 0x000000000000001c 0x000000000000001c  R      0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/zd-linux-x86-64.so.2]
```

Again, note the `0x2e0` file offset. This may be an easier way to get the path to the ELF interpreter.

Now we have the full path to the ELF interpreter.

---

We can now do `ldd /path/to/executable` and we'll get a list of the shared libraries it is/will be using. We'll do this for `fileGood`. Normally, this looks like [redacted]:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc96d43000)
libpython3.7m.so.1.0 => /lib64/libpython3.7m.so.1.0 (0x00007f36d1ee2000)
...
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f36d1ac7000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f36d23ff000)
...
```

---

That's for a normal executable. Here's the `ldd` output for `fileBad`:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc96d43000)
libpython3.7m.so.1.0 => /lib64/libpython3.7m.so.1.0 (0x00007f36d1ee2000)
...
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f36d1ac7000)
/lib64/zd-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3f4f821000)
...
```

---

Okay, to explain ...

`fileGood` is a standard executable [`/bin/vi` on my system]. However, `fileBad` is a *copy* that I made where I *patched* the interpreter path to a non-existent file.

From the `readelf` data, we know the interpreter path. We can check for existence of that file. If it doesn't exist things are [obviously] bad.

With the interpreter path we got from `readelf`, we can find the output line from `ldd` for the interpreter.

For the good file, `ldd` gave us the simple interpreter resolution:

```
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f36d23ff000)
```

For the bad file, `ldd` gave us:

```
/lib64/zd-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3f4f821000)
```

So, either `ldd` or the kernel detected the missing interpreter and substituted the default one.

If we try to exec `fileBad` from the shell we get:

```
fileBad: Command not found
```

If we try to exec `fileBad` from a C program we get an `ENOENT` error:

```
No such file or directory
```

From this we *know* that the *kernel* did *not* try to use a "default" interpreter when we did an `exec*` syscall.

So, we now know that the static analysis we did to determine the ELF interpreter path is valid.

We can be *assured* that the path we came up with *is* [*will be*] the path to the ELF interpreter that the *kernel* will map into the process address space.

---

For further assurance, if you need to, download the kernel source code. Look in the file: `fs/binfmt_elf.c`

---

I think that's sufficient, but to answer the question in your top comment

> with that solution would I not have to race to read `/proc/<pid>/maps` before the program terminates?

There's no need to *race*.

We can control the `fork` process. We can set up the child to run under [the syscall] `ptrace`, so we can control its execution (Note that `ptrace` is what `gdb` and `strace` use).

After we `fork`, but before we `exec`, the child can request that the target of the `exec` sleep until a process attaches to it via `ptrace`.

So, the parent can examine `/proc/pid/maps` [or whatever else] before the target executable has executed a single instruction. It can control execution via `ptrace` [and, eventually, detach to allow the target to run normally].

> Is there a way to predict what PID will be generated next and then wait on its creation in `/proc`?

Given the answer to the first part of your question, this is a bit of a moot point.

There is *no* way to [accurately] predict the `pid` of a process we `fork`. If we *could* determine the `pid` that the system would use *next*, there is *no* guarantee that we will win the *race* against another process doing a `fork` [before us] and "getting" the `pid` we "thought" would be ours.

Comment: Thank you for this elaborate answer, @CraigEstey. You are correct and helped me arrive at a different, complementary conclusion. I was using `ldd` of the system and not the `ldd` of my cross compiler. The cross-compiled `ldd` kept saying `not a dynamic executable` which resulted from the RTLD path in the `ldd` not pointing to the correct dynamic linker that I had in my cross-compiled path. I am wondering if this path isn't correct because I misused `--prefix` or something in my toolchain build.

Answer (score 0):

---

You can use `LD_DEBUG=scopes` for this

Sample output from my machine:

```
LD_DEBUG=scopes ./hello
     17513:
     17513:     Initial object scopes
     17513:     object=./hello [0]
     17513:      scope 0: ./hello /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
     17513:
     17513:     object=linux-vdso.so.1 [0]
     17513:      scope 0: ./hello /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
     17513:      scope 1: linux-vdso.so.1
     17513:
     17513:     object=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0]
     17513:      scope 0: ./hello /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
     17513:
     17513:     object=/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 [0]
     17513:      no scope
     17513:
Hello world
```

Look for the object with no scope.
Also, there are only a couple of values for LD_DEBUG, check them [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) and experiment.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more on the scope option and why "no scope" means it is the dynamic linker?

Comment: @peachykeen It looks as if the scopes are determined by the dynamic linker, so the dynamic linker would have no scope since it wasn't loaded by a dynamic linker.

Comment: I've got a dynamic linker that doesn't respond to LD_DEBUG.

Comment: @Joshua The most obvious thing to do it is to run either of `file` `readelf -l` or `ldd` (or even `hexdump` for that matter) commands on the program that you are about to execute and see which linker it's using but OP already mentioned that.

Comment: @UnslanderMonica thanks for your addition. Does scope define where an object (as shown above) can look to resolve its symbols?